# Encrypting 3000 bytes and more with DES3

Tags: c#, encryption

Im trying to encrypt data with DES3:

```
private byte[] EncryptKey(byte[] wrappedKey)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wrappedKey);
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        cryptoProvider.Key = transportKeyBytes; //key
        cryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        cryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs);
        byte[] key = new Byte[wrappedKey.Length];
        cs.Read(key, 0, wrappedKey.Length);
        cs.Close();
        ms.Close();

        return key;
    }
```

But im getting error saying:

```
Length of the data to encrypt is invalid.
```

Whats the maximum size of the data can be encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using any padding.  That is probably the cause of your error.  By not adding any padding you are only able to encrypt an exact number of 8 byte blocks.  Change the padding to PKCS#5 for DES.

ECB mode is not secure.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) for a (literal) illustration.  Use CBC or CTR mode instead.

3DES is obsolete.  Unless you have to use it for compatibility with an old system use AES instead.

Comment: I think for C# it's `PaddingMode.PKCS7`

Comment: U were totally correct. Figured it out even before i saw answere here (: